# Dynamic created number of columns in Reporting Services 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

Hello all,

I have a table with dynamically created columns (for example M1,M2,M3,...MXX). Number of columns depends on number of months in selected years. Every month has table with more or less columns.

How can I create table in Reporting 2008 when number of columns in table is changing? 
Currently I solve it with setting visible/hidden and I made XX columns, but now the number of columns is too big and I need some better solution.

Thank you for all your solution and opinions.

Adriana

Answer (score 0):

Add column grouping (grouping by month). Then it will change dynamically number of columns based on report month parameter.